# Qt::Tool-Window-Flag for Child of MdiArea

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to apply the Qt::Tool-Window-Flag to a child of a MdiArea. But Qt is not accepting this style. Simply nothing happens while other Window-Flags are working. Does anyone has a clue how to do this?

A possible way of doing this would be using the winapi. But I'm not familiar with it. So if someone has got a snippit I could try it would be really nice.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How exactly the flag applied? Please provide some code.

Comment: Okay. I tried the following ways: ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(obj, Qt::Tool); AND in the constructor of the widget class: QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt::Tools);